# fortran: Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(8)/INTEGER(2))

Tags: linux, makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

I am a beginner of Fortran and running a model written by Fortran. When I tried to compile it, I got an error message like:

```
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgrib_api_f77.so" && ln -s "libgrib_api_f77.so.1.0.0" "libgrib_api_f77.so")
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libgrib_api_f77.a  grib_fortran.o grib_f77.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libgrib_api_f77.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libgrib_api_f77.la" && ln -s "../libgrib_api_f77.la" "libgrib_api_f77.la" )
gfortran   -c -o same_int_long.o same_int_long.f90
same_int_long.f90:23:18:
 
   17 |   call check_long(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
      |                  2
......
   23 |   call check_long(x4(1),x4(2),ret)
      |                  1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/INTEGER(2)).
same_int_long.f90:29:18:
 
   17 |   call check_long(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
      |                  2
......
   29 |   call check_long(x8(1),x8(2),ret)
      |                  1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(8)/INTEGER(2)).
same_int_long.f90:51:17:
 
   45 |   call check_int(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
      |                 2
......
   51 |   call check_int(x4(1),x4(2),ret)
      |                 1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/INTEGER(2)).
same_int_long.f90:57:17:
 
   45 |   call check_int(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
      |                 2
......
   57 |   call check_int(x8(1),x8(2),ret)
      |                 1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(8)/INTEGER(2)).
make[2]: *** [Makefile:546: same_int_long.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/gpfs/home3/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/grib_api-1.17.0-Source/fortran'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:604: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/gpfs/home3/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/grib_api-1.17.0-Source'
make: *** [Makefile:398: /home/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/grib_api-1.17.0-Source-LXgfortran/include/grib_api.mod] Error 2
```

What I did is basically following the installation of the model:

Step1

```
(base) [eccei339@int3 ~]$ mkdir snellius_surfex
(base) [eccei339@int3 ~]$ cp open_surfex_v8_1_20200107.tar-2.gz snellius_surfex/
(base) [eccei339@int3 ~]$ cd snellius_surfex/
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ tar zxvf open_surfex_v8_1_20200107.tar-2.gz
```

…(omit the tar zxvf logging information)

Step 2: some essential env variable

```
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ export VER_MPI="NOMPI"
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ module load 2021
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ module load GCC/10.3.0
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ ls
open_SURFEX_V8_1  open_surfex_v8_1_20200107.tar-2.gz
```

(here I exported some necessary envi var following the instructions of installation of the software)

Step 3: configure

```
(base) [eccei339@int3 snellius_surfex]$ cd open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/
(base) [eccei339@int3 src]$ ls
ASSIM      Makefile            Rules.bullXI15.mk    Rules.MCgfortran.mk  SURFEX
configure  Makefile.SURFEX.mk  Rules.bullXI16.mk    Rules.SX8.mk
FORC       OFFLIN              Rules.LXgfortran.mk  Rules.zgfortran.mk
include    Rules.AIX64.mk      Rules.LXifort.mk     Rules.zifort.mk
LIB        Rules.bgfortran.mk  Rules.LXpgi.mk       scripts
(base) [eccei339@int3 src]$ ./configure
```

(omit the long logging info of the “configure” command)

```
(base) [eccei339@int3 src]$ . ../conf/profile_surfex-LXgfortran-SFX-V8-1-1-NOMPI-OMP-O2-X0
```

(an essential step following the instructions of installation of the software)

Step 4: make the master

```
(base) [eccei339@int3 src]$ make
find: ‘/home/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/dir_obj-LXgfortran-SFX-V8-1-1-NOMPI-OMP-O2-X0/MASTER’: No such file or directory
cd /home/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/grib_api-1.17.0-Source && LDFLAGS= FCFLAGS= CPPFLAGS="" \
 ./configure --disable-jpeg --prefix=/home/eccei339/snellius_surfex/open_SURFEX_V8_1/src/LIB/grib_api-1.17.0-Source-LXgfortran FC="gfortran" && \
 make -j 1 clean && \
 make -j 1 && \
 make -j 1 install && \
 make -j 1 clean
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
```

(omit the long logging information, and the final lines are the error message shown in the beginning of this question description.)

I searched the Internet that this could be due to the GCC 10 is more strict than older GCC (I compiled this model last year with older GCC and made it, but failed this time because our server is transferred to a new system, thus the GCC is upgraded from older version to a new version). Some information from Google said that I could add something like this:

```
export FCFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"
export FFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"
```

But I tried it in the step 2 where I export some essential environmental variables, it still does not work. So I am wondering is there anybody who can help me? Thanks a lot!

Updates: the source code of `grib_api-1.17.0-Source/fortran/same_int_long.f90` from http://distfiles.macports.org/grib_api/ is as following:

```
! Copyright 2005-2016 ECMWF.
!
! This software is licensed under the terms of the Apache Licence Version 2.0
! which can be obtained at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
! 
! In applying this licence, ECMWF does not waive the privileges and immunities granted to it by
! virtue of its status as an intergovernmental organisation nor does it submit to any jurisdiction.

integer function kind_of_long()
  integer(2), dimension(2) :: x2 = (/1, 2/)
  integer(4), dimension(2) :: x4 = (/1, 2/)
  integer(8), dimension(2) :: x8 = (/1, 2/)
  character(len=1) :: ret

  kind_of_long=-1

  call check_long(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_long=2
   return
  endif

  call check_long(x4(1),x4(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_long=4
   return
  endif

  call check_long(x8(1),x8(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_long=8
   return
  endif

end function kind_of_long

integer function kind_of_int()
  integer(2), dimension(2) :: x2 = (/1, 2/)
  integer(4), dimension(2) :: x4 = (/1, 2/)
  integer(8), dimension(2) :: x8 = (/1, 2/)
  character(len=1) :: ret

  kind_of_int=-1

  call check_int(x2(1),x2(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_int=2
   return
  endif

  call check_int(x4(1),x4(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_int=4
   return
  endif

  call check_int(x8(1),x8(2),ret)
  if (ret == 't') then
   kind_of_int=8
   return
  endif

end function kind_of_int

program same_int_long
  integer ki,kl

  ki=kind_of_int()
  kl=kind_of_long()
  if (ki /= kl) then
    write (*,'(i1)') 0
  else
    write (*,'(i1)') 1
  endif
end program same_int_long
```

Here is the full log information of `make`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14rkj2ay39Rv84QBL6UDiSdlIAfhuEt_z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To be able to tell anything we need to see some complete code (MWE) that we can run, at least we need the declarations / definitions of `x..` and `check_long`

Comment: Hi @Albert, thanks for your reply! But I don't think it's about the ```x..``` or ```check_long```...it should be because of the mismatch error...it seems that older GCC can tolerate such mismatch in codes when it compiles them, but the GCC 10 can not...

Comment: You must show the code. Use the declarations of the arguments as they are passed and the declaration inside the subroutine. It is not very likely it is due to GCC10, more likely there is some non-portability in the declarations. Notably, if you knew the cause, you would not have ask here for help, so if people suggest the declarations are necessary, it really means they are likely needed.

Comment: Hi @VladimirF, thanks for your reply! I searched the logging info and found that it is an error in ```gfortran   -c -o same_int_long.o same_int_long.f90``` when I use ```make``` to compile the master. And I couldn't find where this .f90 file is...all I know is from the logging information of ```./configure```, it is in ```grib_api-1.17.0-Source/fortran/same_int_long.f90```...

Comment: @XuShan It is most likely about the `x..` or the `check_long`, the old compilers were a bit more relaxed about variables of different sizes types of different length during compilation resulting in undefined behavior during run time and possible errors. So show your code.

Comment: hi @Albert, yes I agree, I searched ```mismatch error``` by google, and people said it's about GCC 10 is much more stricter than older version. But their solution does not help this case...I tried the ```export FCFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"``` and ```export FFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"``` before I used ```./configure```, but nothing changed...

Comment: I think the source code is in the grid_api-1.17.0, which is http://distfiles.macports.org/grib_api/, under the folder of ```Fortran```. I have updated the source code of ```same_int_long.f90``` to the problem description.

Comment: Please show the output/compilation log when compiling with `-fallow-argument-mismatch`.

Comment: Hi @francescalus, before I show the output/compilation log, may I ask whether I used ```-fallow-argument-mismatch``` correctly? I mean by using ```export FCFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"``` and ```xport FFLAGS="-w -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2"``` before ```./configure```.

Comment: The first block of output you show has the gfortran command line: if you repeat the experiment you will be able to see whether those environment variables have affected the compilation.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are saying...but I repeated the whole procedure with ```-fallow-argument-mismatch``` and without ```-fallow-argument-mismatch```, I found the error is same...they are same about the ```mismatch```

Comment: Hi @francescalus, I am still trying to figure out how to present the logging formation to you...because they are so long....

Comment: Hi @francescalus, I have added the google link for the full logging information for ```make``` into the problem description.

Comment: Hm, they are passing larger integers into a smaller dummy and hoping for the best. And this program checks whether they can get away with that or not. In littleendian it mostly works but it is UGLY AS HELL. Notably, they did not get away with that in this compiler... Updating the code with the `NO_ARG_CHECK` directive should help. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.1.0/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF! But how can I use the ```NO_ARG_CHECK``` for make and configure? and one more thing, I cannot modify the source code for the grib_api package...because the compilation automatically download it from internet or by some other ways, I cannot find the source codes for grid_api in my local directory...

Comment: Where you have the line like `gfortran   -c -o ...` you want to see `gfortran -fallow-argument-mismatch -c -o ...`. If you don't get (something like) that then your configuration hasn't held.

Comment: Hi @francescalus, so you mean that I need to change the ```make``` rules files?

Answer (score 12):

This appened to me with a MPI fortran code. The cause is a decision from gcc developpers on what should be «good interfaces» [see here](https://github.com/Alpine-DAV/ascent/issues/727).
Two solutions in my case :

- Tells gfortran to ignore this concerns with option `-fallow-argument-mismatch`.
- Use modern fortran interface (`use mpi` instead of `include mpif.h`)
  I chose the latter.

Comment: I really wondered what does Deutsches Alpenverein and their alpine ascents have to do with Fortran and MPI...

Comment: This seems to be the same error message, but a somewhat different underlying issue. Useful to know, though.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is about developer opinions about subprogram interfaces.  Rather, it is about their opinions on conforming to Fortran's rules.  Fortran compilers in general and gfortran in particular have traditionally been pretty lax about that by default, but recent gfortran is by default much stricter about parameter / actual argument type matching.

Comment: The `-fallow-argument-mismatch` worked for me. I also ran into the same error when compiling MPI Fortran code using `gfortran` from `gcc-12.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

What you are instantiating as an INTEGER is getting its value assigned by another (variable or declaration)  integer **of a different "byte" memory storage size**.
e.g. in other languages int is 4 bytes and long is 8 bytes. (note) Fortran also has pointers alike C/C++
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vna5/index.html
nb: You did not show the code that has the problem , somewhere around line 29 char 18 in source file same_int_long.f90  ??

Comment: Hi @Samuel Marchant, thanks for your answer! Yes, the code should be in source file ```grib_api-1.17.0-Source/fortran/same_int_long.f90``` (I found this from the logging information of the ```./configure```). But I could not find where this source file is...

Comment: but anyway, I did compile this model out with the exact same files last year...I don't why this time it does not work...the source of the model is the same as the one I used last year...

Comment: noticed another (same_int_long.f90:57:17:) Is that the actual version of code you used last year or is this a different version?

Comment: Yes, the actual version of the code.

Comment: The compiler? same version? I know they are extremely different for each brand regardless same year. e.g. somebodies f90 compiler, same compiler exactly (same platform ?)?

Comment: The compiler is not same. Now our server is updated and we are using gcc 10. But in the last year we are using an older GCC..