setup.py bdist_wheel did not install successfully
I am trying to run a build.py file that I get from github (https://github.com/KiDS-WL/kcap.git), and here I got an error saying setup.py bdist_wheel did not install successfully.
Here is part of the error message:
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [255 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-install-iexgtpky/cosmosis-standalone_2658dc83284a4b0e9c0e50b877f34ffa/setup.py:5: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
.
.
.

      mpifort -O3 -g -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-iexgtpky/cosmosis-standalone_2658dc83284a4b0e9c0e50b877f34ffa/cosmosis/datablock  -std=gnu -ffree-line-length-none -O3 -fPIC -ffree-line-length-none -fno-stack-arrays -DMPI -c -o mpi/mpi_utils.o mpi_utils.F90
      mpi_utils.F90:560:12:

        560 |             seed_point,            &!
            |            1
      ......
        650 |             empty_buffer,      &! not sending anything
            |            2
      Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (REAL(8)/INTEGER(4)).
.
.
.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-iexgtpky/cosmosis-standalone_2658dc83284a4b0e9c0e50b877f34ffa/setup.py", line 142, in <module>
          setup(name = 'cosmosis-standalone',
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 183, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 199, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_wheel.py", line 398, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-iexgtpky/cosmosis-standalone_2658dc83284a4b0e9c0e50b877f34ffa/setup.py", line 122, in run
          compile_library(env)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-iexgtpky/cosmosis-standalone_2658dc83284a4b0e9c0e50b877f34ffa/setup.py", line 82, in compile_library
          subprocess.check_call(["make"], env=env, cwd="cosmosis")
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cosmosis-standalone

I am using WSL on Windows 11
I have tried :

pip install Cmake
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

The problem is with the program make — is it installed? It seems the build process requires it. Why do you install cmake, it's a completely different program?

@phd I saw in the previous post about similar problem, and someone suggested installing cmake. I have just tried pip install make, but it didn't work. The same error message showed up.

You cannot install make with pip — make is not a Python package (you can install cmake because it was packed for pip but it's also not a Python package). To install make use your OS' package manager. AFAIU your OS is WSL (Linux, not Windows) and your package manager is apt (or apt-get, or aptitude, or dselect).

@phd I see. But actually I already had it installed. When I do make --version, it says GNU Make 4.3

Then the problem is that mpifort compiler reported an error. See a similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686755/fortran-error-type-mismatch-between-actual-argument-at-1-and-actual-argument Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mpifort+Error%3A+Type+mismatch+between+actual+argument
